# How compare AIC (akaike information criterior)?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I have two function. First function have a positive value for AIC and the second function have a negative value fir  AIC. How to make comparisons? algebraic or absolute values?? Thanks :)

Comment: What are the two function?, One function (distribution) is sub model of the other or you fit one data on two function(distribution)?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please explain a little more what you're trying to do? AIC is calculated from the likelihood of fitted models & the number of parameters, & the difference in AIC between models is used to compare their likely predictive ability; I'm not sure what these 'functions' are, or what the difference between 'algebraic' & 'absolute' values is.

Comment: +1 to Scortchi's comment. It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do and therefore it's impossible to give an answer. For example, if these two "functions" are based on fitted models with different outcome variables, you shouldn't be comparing them with AIC at all.

Answer (score 3):

When you have two models and you do model selection with AIC, you prefer the model with the minimum value for AIC. So you don't have to take the absolute value of anything and you'd prefer the model with negative AIC in this case.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the answers! And thanks Stijn...that's all I needed to know :)